# How does Apache Spark detect duplicates? Can it be modified?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How does Apache Spark detect duplicate rows?

The reason I am asking is that I would like to have a somewhat different behavior:

Within the set of columns used for duplicate detection, for some of them (which are of type `double`) I would like that duplicate detection was based on the difference between the two values being lower than a certain threshold (specified by me).

I guess this would be possible using `crossJoin()` with appropriate `where` statements afterwards, however, I was hoping for a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It uses `HashArggregate`:

```
scala> df.distinct.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[x#12], functions=[])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(x#12, 200)
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[x#12], functions=[])
      +- LocalTableScan [x#12]
```

> I was hoping for a more elegant solution?

You can try approximate joins provided by LSH operators:

- [Bucketed Random Projection for Euclidean Distance](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#bucketed-random-projection-for-euclidean-distance).
- [MinHash for Jaccard Distance](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#minhash-for-jaccard-distance)

but it is unlikely to work with a single feature.

You can use sessionization-like approach with window functions, but this is useful only if you can divide your data into partitions. If you're fine with approximation you can use fixed size ranges and then apply method I've described in [Spark - Window with recursion? - Conditionally propagating values across rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45277487/6910411)

Another approximation could be achieved with `sort` followed with `mapPartitions`.

```
df.sortBy("someColumn").rdd.mapPartitions(drop_duplicates).toDF()
```

where `dropDuplicates` could be implemented similar to:

```
def drop_duplicates(xs):
    prev = None
    for x in xs:
        if prev is None or abs(x - prev) > threshold:
            yield x
        prev = x
```

With a bit of effort you can make it consistent on partition boundaries as well.

Comment: Thanks for the good&interesting pointers. The thing is: I am trying to get an *exact* solution. For an approximate solution, I could just multiply/divide/round, according to the threshold, and be done with it. BTW: I DO have a `groupID` column which can be used for `Window.partitionBy('groupID')`.